# Analogue of Fermat's "little" theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Let $p$ be a prime, and consider $$S_p(a)=\sum_{\substack{1\le j\le a-1\\(p-1)\mid j}}\binom{a}{j}\;.$$
I have a rather complicated (15 lines) proof that $S_p(a)\equiv0\pmod{p}$. This must be
extremely classical: is there a simple direct proof ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Let $$P(x)=(1+x)^a-1-x^a=\sum_{1 \le j \le a-1} \binom{a}{j}x^j.$$ Working in a field $F$ where $|\{\mu \in F: \mu^{p-1}=1\}|=p-1$ (roots of unity of order $p-1$ exist), we have
$$ \frac{1}{p-1}\sum_{\mu^{p-1}=1}P(x \mu) = \sum_{\substack{1 \le j \le a-1\\(p-1)\mid j}} \binom{a}{j}x^j.$$
We now specialize the field to $\mathbb{F}_p$, and let $x=1$:
$$ -\sum_{\mu \in \mathbb{F}_p^{\times}}P( \mu) = \sum_{\substack{1 \le j \le a-1\\(p-1)\mid j}} \binom{a}{j}.$$
To conclude, observe that $P(0)=0$ and $|\mathbb{F}_p| = p$, so $$\sum_{\mu \in \mathbb{F}_p^{\times}} P(\mu) = \sum_{\mu \in \mathbb{F}_p} P(\mu) = \sum_{\mu \in \mathbb{F}_p} ((1+\mu)^a - \mu^a)=0,$$
because $\mu\mapsto \mu+1$ is a permutation of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

---

A slightly more general congruence is  due to Glaisher (1899), as I've found in a survey by Granville, see [equation (11) here](https://dms.umontreal.ca/%7Eandrew/Binomial/sumsofbcs.html). The precise reference is Glaisher, J. W. L., "A congruence theorem relating to sums of binomial-theorem coefficients.", Quart. J. 30, 150-156, 349-360, 361-383 (1899). See [here for the zbMath review](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A29.0152.05) in German. There is no entry in MathSciNet.

Namely, Glaisher proved that for any $0 \le j_0 \le p-1$ we have
$$\sum_{\substack{1 \le j \le a \\ j \equiv j_0 \bmod (p-1)}} \binom{a}{j} \equiv \binom{k}{j_0} \bmod p$$
where $k$ is any positive integer with $k \equiv a \bmod p$ Applying this with $j_0=0$ and $k=a$, and observing that the term $j=a$ contributes $1 \bmod p$, your result follows. Clicking on equation (11) in the link above leads to a [detailed proof](https://dms.umontreal.ca/%7Eandrew/Binomial/pfeq11.html) which utilizes Lucas' theorem.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a straightforward proof, using generating functions, though it's not as elegant as Ofir's.
We have
$$
\sum_{a=0}^\infty\binom{a}{j}x^a =\frac{x^j}{(1-x)^{j+1}}.
$$
Setting $j=(p-1)k$ and summing on $k$ gives
$$
\sum_{a=0}^\infty x^a \sum_{p-1\mid j}\binom{a}{j} = \frac{(1-x)^{p-1}}{(1-x)^p -x^{p-1}(1-x)}. 
$$
We subtract $\sum_{a=0}^\infty x^a \binom{a}{0} = 1/(1-x)$ and
$$\sum_{\substack{p-1\mid a\\ a>0}}x^a\binom{a}{a} = \frac{x^{p-1}}{1-x^{p-1}}$$
to get
$$
\sum_{a=0}^\infty S_p(a) x^a =  \frac{(1-x)^{p-1}}{(1-x)^p -x^{p-1}(1-x)}
 -\frac{1}{1-x} -\frac{x^{p-1}}{1-x^{p-1}}.
$$
Modulo $p$, we may replace $(1-x)^{p-1}$ with $(1-x^p)/(1-x)$ and $(1-x)^p$ with $1-x^p$, obtaining
\begin{align*}
\sum_{a=0}^\infty S_p(a) x^a &\equiv  \frac{(1-x^p)/(1-x)}{1-x^p -x^{p-1}(1-x)}
 -\frac{1}{1-x} -\frac{x^{p-1}}{1-x^{p-1}}\pmod{p}\\
 &=0.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

Actually, a further extension was given in my paper [Combinatorial congruences and Stirling numbers](http://maths.nju.edu.cn/%7Ezwsun/92a.pdf) [Acta Arith. 126 (2007), 387-398]. Now I state Corollary 1.3 (a consequence of Theorem 1.1) in the 2007 paper of mine.

Let $p$ be a prime. If $l,l',m$ are positive integers with $l'\ge l>m/p$ and
$l'\equiv l\pmod {(p-1)p^{\lfloor\log_p m\rfloor}}$, then
$$\sum_{j\equiv r\pmod {p-1}}\binom{l'}j S(j,m)
\equiv\sum_{j\equiv r\pmod {p-1}}\binom{l}j S(j,m)\pmod p,$$
where $S(j,m)$ denotes the Stirling number of the second kind.

In the case $m=1$, this yields Glaisher's result.